# Send Email Based on Which Checkbox(s) is Selected

Tags: php, forms

I'm learning PHP and have a question that I hope has a simple answer.  I've created basic forms in the past and sent a corresponding email back to the user upon submission.

This time, I have 3 checkboxes.  Depending on which checkbox is selected, I need a certain email sent to them.

For example, if they wish to receive document 1 and 3, then submit, the email will send them the links to download those two documents, and so on.

I don't mind if it even sends two emails, one for each checkbox selection.  If they select two documents they wish to receive, they get one email for a link to document 1 and another for document 3.

I'm not sure if I can even do this with PHP or not.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with PHP. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
// create an array with the checkboxes so you can later easily expand it
// the indexes of the array are the fieldnames of the checkboxes
$checkboxes = array(
    'checkbox1' => 'http://example.com/somelink',
    'checkbox2' => 'http://example.com/somelink2',
    'checkbox3' => 'http://example.com/somelink3',
);

// generate mail body based on checked checkboxes
$mailContents = 'Your links:';
foreach($checkboxes as $name => $link) {
    if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
        $mailContents.= $link . "\n";
    }
}
```

Now you can mail the links contained in `$mailContents` as string.

Answer (score 0):

Set a value for every checkboxes and then use the POST or the GET method to send the value of the three checkboxes and then you do:

```
if(check1 == "value"){
   //send email 1
}
if(check2 == "value"){
   //send email 2
}
if(check3 == "value"){
   //send email 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is the following:
Create the checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sendDoc1" value="Selected" /> Send me Document 1
```

Then when php checks the form you can use isset and check the content of the input

```
if(isset($_POST['sendDoc1']) &&
$_POST['sendDoc1'] == 'Selected')
{
  //Code to send email
}
```

and you can repeat that for each document

Answer (score 0):

Create a form with your document checkboxes

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    Document 1: <input type="checkbox" name="document[]" value="document1" /><br />
    Document 2: <input type="checkbox" name="document[]" value="document2" /><br />
    Document 3: <input type="checkbox" name="document[]" value="document3" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

and a php script to handle it

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST) && ($_POST['send'] == 1)){

        $documents = array(
                        'document1' => 'http://www.example.com/document1.doc',
                        'document2' => 'http://www.example.com/document2.doc',
                        'document3' => 'http://www.example.com/document3.doc'
                    );

        $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
        $subject = 'the subject';
        $message = "hello\n\n";

        if(isset($_POST['document']) && count($_POST['document']) > 0){
            foreach($_POST['document'] as $doc){
                if(isset($documents[$doc])){
                    $message .= "Here is ".$documents[$doc]."\n";
                }
            }
        }


        $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
?>
```

I think you got the general idea.